# Trying to call a PHP script in separate JS file, how do i display the output onto my HTML page

Tags: php, html, xml

First time trying this can anyone help me, i get an output on the console but have no idea how to display it in a  tag. This is the problem for both the sections of my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const URL_GETOFFERS = 'getOffers.php';
const URL_GETOFFERS_XML = 'getOffers.php?useXML';

fetch(URL_GETOFFERS)
    .then(
        function (response) {
            return response.text();
        })
    .then(
        function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById("getHTMLOffer").innerHTML = "<p>" + this.responseText + "</p>";
        })
    .catch(
        function (err) {
            console.log("Something went wrong!", err);
        });

fetch(URL_GETOFFERS_XML)
    .then(
        function (response) {
            return response.text();
        })
    .then(
        function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
            xmlDoc.getElementsById("getXMLOffer").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        })
    .catch(
        function (err) {
            console.log("Something went wrong!", err);
        });
 });
```

Comment: @getset Sorry, in an <aside> tag.  Just as text that i can see is outputted in the console.

Comment: I think that ought to be `data` rather than `this.responseText` when attempting to display in html

Comment: @RamRaider I have changed that thank you, do you know what i should put in the HTML for it to display?

Comment: what html? Can you add that to the question

Comment: @RamRaider I would like to display the output of the this code in a HTML <aside> tag on my homepage. The code above outputs in the console but I do not know how to display said output onto the actual page.

Comment: so-changing `this.responseText` to `data` in `document.getElementById("getHTMLOffer").innerHTML = "<p>" + data + "</p>";` did not work?

Comment: @RamRaider sadly not, I don't know if because this is a separate JS file to my homepage, i'd need to put something on there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put some content inside HTML elements you have to:

- create the desired HTML elements

```
<div id="getHTMLOffer">initial content</div>
<div id="getXMLOffer">initial content</div>
```

- `get` the elements in Javascript, after DOM has loaded
- change the contents of the elements

```
    // the contents of this function is executed after the HTML structure (DOM) is loaded
    // aka `on ready`
    (function() { 
        document.getElementById("getHTMLOffer").innerHTML = "new content here";
        document.getElementById("getXMLOffer").innerHTML = "new content here";
    })();
```

Know that there are multiple ways to accomplish this. Above is shown just one of those ways.

Also be aware the function `getElementById` gets only one element. In your code there is a typo `getElementsById` (extra `s` character).

Comment: Thank you so much this has made the getHTMLOffer display, is there a way to have both the getHTMLOffer and getXMLOffer to display on same page?

Answer (score 0):

A rudimentary example that sends a basic GET request with a querystring to the same page, processes th servers response and displays on the page

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset( $_GET['task'] ) ){
        ob_clean();
        echo 'Some text as respons to the FETCH request task = "'.$_GET['task'].'"';
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>FETCH</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <aside id='getHTMLOffer'></aside>
        <script>
            fetch( '?task=fetch&source=text' )
            .then( r=>{ return r.text() } )
            .then( data=>{
                document.getElementById('getHTMLOffer').innerHTML=data
            })
            .catch(err=>{ alert( err ) } )
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```